# Asset thumbnail size in Entries

Tags: assets, image-transforms

Is there a quick an easy way to change the asset thumbnail size when it's attached to an entry?

By default this is quite small and restrictive and would like to show a more representative version of the image when add/editing each entry.

I would have thought this is possible using a transform but how would this be tied back to the entry form?

Comment: Do you mean in the assets field in the control panel, or in your templates?

Comment: "when add/editing each entry" → I think he is talking cp.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm referring to the thumbnails in CP, I'm fine with transforms in my templates.

Answer (score 4):

No, you currently can't do that. But it's on The List! :)

See discussions in g+ here:

https://plus.google.com/110899911634334728373/posts/Q4Vi5d1y8Ry
https://plus.google.com/114292096121951987560/posts/PdXYBMxqbzb

Comment: It would be absolutely stellar if it could be pushed up on the list somehow, as I've had 2 clients decide on EE because of this feature and the timing of their projects.

Comment: @jpea you better write this on g+, as I don't expect someone of P+T to read this comment hidden behind this "old" question.